# WPF inline x:Array on Binding

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to use inline arrays in XAML?

I'm trying to transform something like this:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Property>
        <Binding Path="MyVariable" Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <x:Array Type="s:Boolean">
                    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                </x:Array>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </Control.Property>
</Control>
```

Into something like this:

```
<Control Property="{Binding MyVariable, 
 Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
 ConverterParameter={x:Array s:Boolean, Items=[]{ {s:Boolean True}; {s:Boolean False} }}}" 
/>
```

But Visual Studio shows me following error bellow "Property":

> The TypeConverter for “IList” does not support converting from a string

OBS:

- I don't know if thats the correct syntax for inline x:Array in XAML, I wrote that because its the only one that VS didn't whine about
- Of course the example doesn't seem practical, it's just an easy way of showing what I'm looking for

Comment: Why are you trying to transform the XAML in the first place...?

Comment: This can probably be done via custom markup extension, but really, why?

Comment: Pure syntax sugar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use inline arrays in XAML?

No. I am afraid there is no valid syntax for defining an array "inline" in XAML.

You could define it as reusable resource with an `x:Key`:

```
<x:Array x:Key="array" Type="s:Boolean">
    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
</x:Array>
```

..and then reference it using the `StaticResource` markup extension.

```
<Control Property="{Binding MyVariable, 
         Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
         ConverterParameter={StaticResource arr}}" />
```

Or you could define a custom array class and define it as a resource:

```
<local:MyCollectionType />
```

You can for example populate the custom type with items in its constructor if you don't want to waste a few more lines in your XAML markup. But there is no built-in support for something like this:

```
Items=[]{ {s:Boolean True}; {s:Boolean False} }}}"
```

Yet another approach would be to create a [custom markup expression](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf/).

Comment: Fair enough. I'm still really curious about why VS seems to understand that syntax as an IList